Anime where a demon lord created new "unbeatable" magic that's regular attack magic 60 years later
I only saw the untranslated title in a short but this stuck with me. a demon king resurrection event where he's impressed they're using the type of magic he created and the dome shaped hexagon grid protection magic a female side protagonist (rocking Final Fantasy black mage garb iirc) blocks his own with. He asks how long it's been, and the girl answers 60 years. They kill him there while they still can, because he's already coming up with ways around the shield. The magic involved CGI magic circles, no chanting, nothing distinct, mostly tropes as far as character design. The demon guy reminded me of Calamity (Atrocity?) from I Don't Want To Get Hurt So I'll Max Defense, and from the community discussion, this was not the main antagonist or the only season of the show.

That's from Frieren: Beyond Journey's End. The scene in question is from Episode 3:

 Frieren offers Qual a peaceful death if he cooperates, but undeterred, Qual
 instead casts defensive magic and observes how it attunes to and disperses offensive spells, realizing its significant mana consumption. He retaliates with a barrage of Zoltraak spells.

I did like it very much, so much so it may actually become my GOAT Anime series.

Yep, this is definitely Frieren. Here's a clip of the fight: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pubJzYdUg7g

100% that's the one, thanks y'all. i guess it was White Mage and Harry Potter robes, though.
